# How do I manage FileScopes in HPCC version 7/8*?

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I got a HPCC community version 8.0.0.1 installation running. Whenever I try to add a new FilScope trhoug ECL Watch nothing happens. It simply doesn't create it.

I got some version 6.4 clusters running and this problem doesn't happen. Works fine there.

When I try to delete Scopes created on ver 6 through version 8 I got the error "BaseDN not specified". On the logs I see the same thing.

I am not missing any basedn configuration of the already in place basedn fields on environment.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this question. I just did some research, and found that this problem has been reported and is fixed in a newer release. Please try build 8.6.42 or newer.
FYI, it was fixed with this issue
https://track.hpccsystems.com/browse/HPCC-27892

Russ Whitehead

Comment: I don't have access to this isse, even registering to the channel. Could you please post what was the issue and resolution if I can replicate it in older versions.

Comment: Murilo, the problem was in the ECLWatch component, it was not correctly passing the baseDN to ESP and the security manager. If you must use an older version of HPCC, trying placing ECLWatch in "Tech Preview" mode by clicking the slider with that same name, on the top right hand side of ECLWatch. I'm not sure when Tech Preview was added though...

Comment: Murilo, I just wanted to follow up and make sure you saw my answer, and hopefully were able to install the newer build and verify this feature works to your satisfaction

Comment: Hey William. Thanks for the answer. It did worked on version 8.6.42 that you mentioned. But older versions like 7.x.x doesnt have this "tech preview" feature. I was looking for enabling this configuration on 7.x.x if it's possible. Do you happen to know that?